# How to Pre-load MainActivity in SplashActivity so there would be no delay when launching MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have a working splash

```
public class MainSplash extends AppCompatActivity  {
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainSplash.this, MainMenu.class);
            MainSplash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainSplash.this.finish();
        }

    },   SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
}
```

and I want to add few buttons like `share`, `more` etc

and wen I do that by removing handler and `SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH`, and adding buttons to xml and handling clicks on them just like any other other activity and set a `Start` button to start `MainActivity`, **the `MainActivity` starts in few seconds ( after 1, 2 seconds of loading).**

**But I want to handle the loading time of `MainActivity` in `SplashActivity`**,

How can I do that?

Here is the example `SplashActivity` after adding buttons

```
public class MainSplash extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
//private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button4:
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            finish();
            break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What you want is still unclear even u posted a brief question..

Comment: @Brendon check it again please if it makes sens or ill edit it again

Comment: If you use a splash screen, why you want add some button in this. What will happen if user want click on some button but not enough time, because ``MainActivity`` is loaded after 2 second ???

Comment: @DanhDC please check second part of the code, i will remove time, main activity will start on button click, i just wish main activity starts instantly after the press of `button4`, i.e it loads in background while user is interacting with splash

Comment: Are you check how many time used to load ``MainActivity``. if have many data get from server, you can get it in ``MainSplash `` and put it to ``MainActivity`` use ``Intent.putExtra``.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding delay in loading time of `MainActivity` by putting a `handler` inside `onCLick`

Comment: please read my question again, especially the bold part, i want to decrease loading time

Comment: if an `activity` is started it will always be visible to the user, if you want some background work, you can try using asynchtask, on button `onclick` and in `postExecute` you may start `mainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

well if anyone else having the same issue like when we load `Mainactivity` from `SplashActivity` we get a black screen for a second or two, which is the loading time for the `MainActivity` and it really doesn't look good.

To make it go away i just added a `Fragment` for splash Screen instead of `SplashActivity` and another fragment for Main interface.

This way Activity loads when app start so and transaction from splash fragment to main fragment takes no time :)

Hope it helps someone.